# How to display multiple columns as rows + columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have this table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE #t1
(
  [Year]      int,
  Student     int,
  Test        char(2),
  Score       int,
  Achievement varchar(32)
);

INSERT #t1 VALUES
(2014,1,'MA',697, 'Proficient'),
(2013,1,'CA',641, 'Basic'),
(2015,1,'MA',2447,'Below Basic'),
(2017,1,'MA',464, 'Proficient'),
(2012,1,'CA',611, 'Below Basic'),
(2014,1,'MA',749, 'Advanced'),
(2016,1,'CA',459, 'Below Basic'),
(2013,1,'MA',779, 'Advanced');
```

Now I want to create a SQL query from `#t1` in which the result should be like this:

[image: <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaLZo.png" width="450">]

Comment: The answer to the subject of your question is *pivot* but what you are doing is essentially an execel or ssrs like display... so handle it in the presentation layer.

Comment: Hello, please show tables, queries and all other data in a textual way and avoid screenshots. Keep in mind that not everyone has access to images on imgur.com. Often these kind of sites are blocked by corporate firewalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to create a matrix of test/year combos. For each test, you need to "pivot" both the score and achievement for each year (but we're not using `PIVOT` here, because you're not pivoting a single aggregation). I use dynamic SQL for this. Presumably you are passing in a single `Student` at a time?

```
DECLARE @StudentID int = 1;  -- input parameter to a stored procedure

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
UNION ALL SELECT Test'
    + REPLACE((SELECT ', Score' + y + ' = MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = ' 
    + y + ' AND Test=''$t$'' THEN Score END),
      Achivement' + y + ' = MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = ' 
    + y + ' AND Test=''$t$'' THEN Achievement END)'
  FROM (SELECT RTRIM([Year]) AS y FROM #t1 GROUP BY [Year]) y
  ORDER BY y FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'$t$',t.Test)
  + N' FROM #t1 WHERE Test = ''' + t.Test + ''' AND Student = @StudentID GROUP BY Test'
FROM #t1 AS t GROUP BY t.Test;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 12, '');

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@StudentID int', @StudentID;
```

Results (yes, I incorrectly spelled it `Achivement`):

> [image]

This gets a little closer to your screen shot:

```
DECLARE @StudentID int = 1; -- input param, hopefully for a stored procedure

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT [x]=''''';

SET @sql += (SELECT ',[x]=''' + RTRIM([Year]) + ''',[x]='''''
  FROM #t1 GROUP BY [Year]
  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.[1]','nvarchar(max)');

SET @sql += '
UNION ALL SELECT ''''' + (SELECT ',''Score'',''Achievement'''
  FROM #t1 GROUP BY [Year]
  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.[1]','nvarchar(max)');

SELECT @sql += N'
UNION ALL SELECT Test'
  + REPLACE((SELECT ', Score' + y + ' = MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = ' 
  + y + ' AND Test=''$t$'' THEN RTRIM(Score) END),
    Achievement' + y + ' = MAX(CASE WHEN [Year] = ' 
  + y + ' AND Test=''$t$'' THEN Achievement END)'
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM([Year]) AS y FROM #t1) y
      ORDER BY y FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),'$t$',t.Test)
      + N' FROM #t1 WHERE Test = ''' + t.Test + ''' AND Student = @StudentID GROUP BY Test'
    FROM #t1 AS t GROUP BY t.Test;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@StudentID int', @StudentID;
```

Results:

> [image]

If you want to display the year on top of both columns, you'll have to figure that out at the presentation layer. T-SQL doesn't have a concept of `colspan`. This will always be ugly in T-SQL because it isn't a presentation language - you should figure out how to flip these rowsets sideways in whatever front end language is being used.